# Restore GRUB after Windows 10 install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I've had a dual boot on my laptop; the first onboard HDD with Windows 7, and second SSD with Ubuntu. GRUB was installed on 1 drive and it was in boot option in BIOS. All works well, on startup the GRUB menu offered me to choose between them.

Today i updated my Win7 to Win10 with formatting system logical drive. Windows starts by default but there was no GRUB menu. I've read I should make a Live USB with Ubuntu, load from it, install boot-repair and just press Big Button.

I've tried a boot from second (SSD) drive and it works! Ubuntu loaded without any problems, but without GRUB menu, too. OK, I ran the boot-repair tool and press the button.

Unfortunately, I didn't save the report link at this time =( After reboot there were no Windows 10, no GRUB menu, just Ubuntu automatically loads.

In BIOS there were SSD as primary boot option, changed it to HDD, after reboot there were old GRUB menu with Ubuntu and Win7, but neither Win7 or Win10 would load.

After that I tried to configure boot-repair and set default OS to Windows (via sdb5 menu), but no luck. [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HsvhGBC4gY/) i saved link to report.

Now GRUB menu loads without Windows, only Ubuntu, Ubuntu with options and load BIOS options available. In the report I see I have many parts of older installations (Win8 which was on laptop out of box and replaced by Win7 five years ago, plus another Win7 since deleted).

[Here's](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5pyQxrshS3/) the last report from boot-repair. What should I do now to restore ability to dual boot, and, if it possible, to cleanup my drives?

Comment: You should not mix BIOS & UEFI. With 2 drives you technically can, but only can dual boot from UEFI, never from grub. Grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode. Also do not run auto fix in Boot-Repair with two drives. You want Windows boot loader in MBR for BIOS boot. Use Boot-Repair's advanced mode. Or reinstall Windows in UEFI mode to gpt and install Ubuntu in UEFI mode to gpt drive. Ubuntu is on MBR drive in UEFI boot mode which can work but is not recommended.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, if your Ubuntu is close to new, you can start over, make a clean installation following advices of @oldfred. Your Ubuntu has been pretty much used and contains important data, use fsarchiver or clonezilla to backup it and restore after the clean installation. However, duel-boot is not use in my opinion, you can use  one OS at a time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Reinstall windows with cleanup all drives, ubuntu next in line